# I've been trying to install pygame, but i keep getting this error:

Tags: windows-10, python, setup, pip

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\pichau\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Pichau\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-um6lts5v\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Pichau\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-um6lts5v\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-um6lts5v\pygame\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-um6lts5v\pygame\
Complete output (17 lines):


WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...


Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-um6lts5v\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-um6lts5v\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-um6lts5v\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-um6lts5v\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
    reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: check your command as it says.... there's a lot in it, so triple and quadruple check that before running in script.

Comment: Just upgraded to Python38, and have the same error trying to install pygame, pgzero, scipy, matplotlib.  Think there's a Python 2 library mixup as the last but one line mentions raw_input() - this is obsolete in Python3.

Comment: Was running all the modules mentioned in previous comment sucessfully in python37.

Comment: Think it's a Python38 issue - reverted to 3.7 which installed pygame fine - but I'm getting a sub-process error when I try to run - that's why I've upgraded to 3.8 (no sub-process error) but just can't install the modules I use to teach my high school kids! :-(

Comment: Same issue posted here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469733/pip-install-eoferror

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a build of 2.0.0.dev3 for Python 3.8. Python 3.8 wasn't out when dev3 was released. You want the latest, so change your command to:

```
python3 -m pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

Answer (score 1):

The currently official pygame 1.9.6 is not compatible with Python 3.8, but there's a 2.0.0.dev6 version which is somewhat OK but still not enabled as available module for pip